# Unable to send email on main server in web2py

Tags: email, web2py

Hie folks.. I am unable to send email in server(to be specific webfaction.com) ...
but it's running fine on local host
all these three lines in db.py are set to true..

> auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True
>   auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = True
>   auth.settings.reset_password_requires_verification = True

When I complete the registration form a flash appears on the top-right corner of the page with a flash message "Unable to send mail"
These are the settings of the mail server in db.py

> mail = auth.settings.mailer
>   mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
>   mail.settings.sender = 'fakeid425ster@gmail.com'
>   mail.settings.tls = False
>   mail.settings.login ='fakeid425ster@gmail.com:secret'

Answer (score 1):

All the issues I have experienced with sending email ("unable to send email") from Web2Py via Gmail, have been caused by the 2-steps authentication which was enabled on my gmail account.

In order for Web2Py to be able to send email via gmail:

1. Read Google instructions at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en
2. When logged in with your gmail account, go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords?pli=1 and enter the once-only pwd Google provides with the app you intend to allow use the gmail services (I have mentioned "Web2Py")
3. In the model where the mail services are defined - use exactly what's recommended in the W2P book with the new pwd mentioned above - and it works !

NeoToren

Answer (score 0):

carefully check following url

http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08

i have used 587 successfully in the past.

i noticed that username if not a gmail account is the full email address
like:

bob@foo.com:password

You might need to set mail.settings.tls = True.

Comment: @premjith... nope no luck there mate.. !!

Comment: same here. Seems like all of my db.py settings are not working  e.g auth.messages.submit_button = 'Submit' # 'Suibbbmmiitt!!!'

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change

```
mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
```

into

```
mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:465'
```

and try to remove this line  :

```
mail.settings.tls = False
```

For debugging purposes you can also set

```
mail.settings.server = 'logging'
```

Emails will not be sent but logged to the console instead. (http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08#Setting-up-email)

Comment: Did you manage to send regular emails from a controller?
See an example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085738/i-am-trying-send-email-using-web2py-with-gmail-and-using-smtp-setting-i-have-att/19090283#19090283

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses some kind of authentication for servers from US(in my case it's US) but when I used the settings for the mailbox of webfaction.com guys it worked....
thanx for the reply anyway ...

> from gluon.tools import Mail
>   mail = Mail()
>   mail = auth.settings.mailer
>   mail.settings.server =  'smtp.webfaction.com:25'
>   mail.settings.sender
>   = 'email'
>   mail.settings.login = 'email:password'